# End Amazon Connect call if Store user input does not register any input

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

all. I have a Contact Flow in which a customer is greeted. The customer is asked to input a nine digit ID number, the time-out before first entry is set to 5 seconds, and the '#' symbol specifies the end of input. However, if the customer doesn't input any value the system continues the flow as it was a success instead of terminating the call.
Desired use case is: 
1- Customer calls 
2- A prompt tells the customer to input the numbers 
3- A save customer input block waits for the input 
4- If no input is given within 5-10 seconds the call must be terminated

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Very nice use case to solve. Generally in the Stored Customer Input block either you have success or error. This can be handled with the below workaround solution
In a store customer input when you don't put anything then Stored Customer Input value gets returned with Timeout. You can have the returned value as a check in the Check Contact attribute to terminate the call
I have attached the check contact attribute block for your reference [Sample Call Flow Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugnqx.png).[Check Contact Attribute Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMviJ.png)

Comment: Thank you for attaching those images, those did help to make things more clear. Will look into modifying my contact flow as suggested.